# Copy values from real value column to decimal value column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In one of our SQL tables, we have a real field. Precision of real field is 7. We need more precision in our application. So we decided to convert our real field to decimal field.

Since our table is very large and since we cannot turn off transaction logs, we decided on the following approach.

- Rename real column to real_value_old (Previous name was real_value)
- Create new real column with name real_value and data type decimal(38,
  8)
- Copy values from real_value_old to real_value in batches

We are facing some problems with this approach.
For example, if real_value_old is 545370.2, real_value is getting set as 545370.18750000

When we checked the issue, we figured it is because of the following issue

```
update table set real_value = cast (real_value_old as decimal(38,8)) where some_condition
update table set real_value = ROUND(cast (real_value_old as decimal(38,8)), 8) where some_condition
update table set real_value = convert (decimal(38,8), real_value_old, 38) where some_condition
update table set real_value = real_value_old  where some_condition
```

In all the above cases,
if real_value_old is 545370.2, real_value is getting set as 545370.18750000

Can somebody provide a solution here?

This code quickly shows exactly what the problem is. Confirmed on sql server 2012

```
DECLARE @real REAL = 545370.2
SELECT cast(@real AS DECIMAL(38, 8))
    ,ROUND(cast(@real AS DECIMAL(38, 8)), 8)
    ,convert(DECIMAL(38, 8), @real, 38)
```

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? What's the exact data type for `real_value_old`?

Comment: SQL Server is the DBMS. Exact data type for real_value_old is real

Comment: How do you know that the value in `real_value_old` is `545370.2` instead of `545370.1875`

Comment: when I do, select * from table, I am getting 545370.2 as value for real_value_old

Comment: update table set real_value = ROUND(CAST (real_value_old AS decimal (38,8)),1)  where some_condition

not sure if this help ?

Comment: Even update table set real_value = ROUND(CAST (real_value_old AS decimal (38,8)),8) sets real_value as 545370.18750000. I am editing the question and putting your suggestion also there

Comment: update table set real_value = ROUND(CAST (real_value_old AS decimal (38,8)),1) will set it as 545370.2. But the number of decimal points we need is not always one.

Comment: Thanks ah_hau. I am able to develop the solution from your suggestion. update table set real_value = ROUND(CAST (real_value_old AS decimal (38,8)), @decimalDigits) will work

Comment: great to see you found the solution :)

Comment: *‘when I do, select * from table, I am getting 545370.2’* – where are you doing and getting that? I experimented with 545370.25 and 545370.3 in SSMS. When I did just `SELECT @real`, SSMS rendered it for me as 545370.3 *in each case*, but `SELECT CAST(@real AS DECIMAL(38, 8))` returned 545370.25000000 and 545370.31250000 respectively. My point is, your data are already imprecise to the point that the original/intended values are probably impossible to recover.

Comment: As explained in the question, I am trying to copy value from a real column to decimal column and then want to get rid of real column. When I convert 545370.3 to DECIMAL, I just expect a precision of 7. That means, when 545370.3 is converted to DECIMAL, I am expecting 545370.3 or 545370.30 or 545370.30000000, but not 545370.25000000 and not 545370.31250000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below link will give function to get number of digits for float data type

[How to get the count of digits after the decimal point in a float column in ms sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953129/how-to-get-the-count-of-digits-after-the-decimal-point-in-a-float-column-in-ms-s)

Modify that function to use REAL in function argument
and then, the below sql will work

```
update table set real_value = ROUND(CAST (real_value_old AS decimal (38,8)), dbo.countDigits(real_value_old)) where some_condition
```

Complete code is given below

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.countDigits(@A real) RETURNS tinyint AS
BEGIN
declare @R tinyint
IF @A IS NULL 
   RETURN NULL
set @R = 0
while @A - str(@A, 18 + @R, @r) <> 0
begin
   SET @R = @R + 1
end
RETURN @R
END
GO

DECLARE @real REAL = 545370.2
SELECT ROUND( cast(@real AS DECIMAL(38, 8)), dbo.countDigits(@real))
```

Comment: This seems nice but note that it still won't let you tell between, say, 545370.16 and 545370.21 (stored as `real`).

Comment: You can't store 545370.16 and 545370.21 in a REAL column (Since max precision is 7. Both these values will get stored as 545370.2). I am working on a legacy application which already uses a REAL column. I am trying to copy REAL values to a DECIMAL column and then want to get rid of REAL column.

Comment: Oh I see, it's only about recovering the value within the max precision of `real`. Well, the method makes perfect sense then.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a REAL datatype from the documentation of MSDN:

*Approximate-number data types for use with floating point numeric data. Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly. The ISO synonym for real is float(24).*

This example shows how this works out in the real world (pun intented)

```
DECLARE @real REAL = 545370.2
SELECT cast(@real AS DECIMAL(38, 8))
    ,ROUND(cast(@real AS DECIMAL(38, 8)), 8)
    ,convert(DECIMAL(38, 8), @real, 38)
```

Each of these results in 545370.18750000

```
 DECLARE @float float(24) = 545370.2
SELECT cast(@float AS DECIMAL(38, 8))
    ,ROUND(cast(@float AS DECIMAL(38, 8)), 8)
    ,convert(DECIMAL(38, 8), @float, 38)
```

Same as the first block

```
 DECLARE @doublefloat float(53) = 545370.2
SELECT cast(@doublefloat AS DECIMAL(38, 8))
    ,ROUND(cast(@doublefloat AS DECIMAL(38, 8)), 8)
    ,convert(DECIMAL(38, 8), @doublefloat, 38)
```

Double precision float gets it right though: 545370.20000000

So there you go. Dont use aproximate numbers when the results aren't allowed to be aproximated and study your datatypes to avoid headaches ;)

**EDIT:**
The specific number given in the example can be handled like this:

```
DECLARE @float real = 545370.2
SELECT CEILING(@float*10)/10
```

Depending on the range of numbers you are treating you can look at a formula using CEILING/FLOOR/ROUND that works for the entire range.

Comment: I know that REAL is an approximate data type. I am working on a legacy application and I am trying to move away from REAL data type. The question asked above came while moving from REAL to DECIMAL